# How to get out of fullscreen mode?

Tags: geany

I was stuck in Geany in fullscreen mode and unable to get out. All the suggestions I found on websites were too complicated (for me). I finally discovered that by depressing the ALT key and the V key, the view menu opens and I was able to uncheck fullscreen mode. Problem solved.

This appears to be the way one sees menus while in fullscreen mode: ALT + , e.g., File Edit View etc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pressing Keys <kbd>F11</kbd> toggles Geany full screen mode.

Source: http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#notebook-tab-keybindings

Comment: CTRL+Q would kill Geany (completely close and exit).  And if you start it back it will start in full screen mode.  Pressing F11 will do the trik.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me on a guest Ubuntu running with VMware on a mac host.

I changed the line `fullscreen=true` in file `~/.config/geany/geany.conf` to `fullscreen=false`.

Answer (score 0):

I run Ubuntu on VirtualBox and tried the above tricks and it didn't worked out on windows 8.1.
 What I did to exit command line full screen was :

1. **Right click** on the terminal
2. select **Leave Full Screen**

And I got the normal screen again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> but it had to be the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button.